# Custom logger using log4j for spark scala application when executed using oozie

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, oozie-workflow

I have developed a spark scala application and used log4j for logger and is working fine when i execute it using the spark-submit as below :

```
spark-submit --name "Test" --class com.comp.test  --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/myid/log4j.properties' --queue=root.user /home/myid/dev/data.jar
```

The works fine and I get my log file created at the specified directory in the log4j.properties.

Now, When I run the same using Oozie spark action , the log file at the specific directory as mentioned in the log4j.properties is not getting created.

**log4j.properties:**

```
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/home/myid/dev/log/dev.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n


# By default, everything goes to console and file
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, myConsoleAppender, RollingAppender

# The noisier spark logs go to file only
log4j.logger.spark.storage=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.storage=false
log4j.logger.spark.scheduler=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.scheduler=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTracker=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivty.spark.MapOutputTracker=false
```

**Oozie workflow :**

```
<workflow-app name="OozieApp" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5">
    <start to="LoadTable"/>
    <kill name="Kill">
        <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <action name="LoadTable">
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapreduce.job.queuename</name>
                    <value>root.user</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <master>yarn</master>
            <mode>client</mode>
            <name>OozieApp</name>
              <class>com.comp.test</class>
            <jar>data.jar</jar>
              <spark-opts>--queue=root.user --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions='-Dlog4j.configuration=file:/home/myid/log4j.properties' </spark-opts>

        </spark>
        <ok to="End"/>
        <error to="Kill"/>
    </action>
    <end name="End"/>
</workflow-app>
```

Could you help me get the custom log created in log directory when executed using oozie spark action ?

I can use shell action and use spark-submit , but I prefer spark action itself.

Comment: _"log file is not being created"_ > Oozie submits its launcher job to Yarn, which runs the Spark driver on a random node, which submits its own job to Yarn, which runs the executors on random nodes. So... you mean that you connected to each and every node to check for your random log files, and did not find any? Right?

Comment: Anything in the Yarn logs (for both jobs, the one spawned by Oozie and the one spawned by Spark) about Log4J complaining?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I didnot/couldn't check for logs in all the nodes where the job ran. I only have access to edge node. Hence my goal to to get the logs in the edge node itself. All the custom logs are shown in the resource manager app logs under the stderr/stdout as excepted , I want them to be available in the edgenode as well.

Comment: Then start a Flume service on the Edge node, configured to dump messages to a local file; add the Flume Log4J plugin to your job dependencies, update the Log4J conf for your job so that it logs *also* to your Flume service; and try to sort out the mess afterwards...